# How to change the icon for the matplotlib 'configure subplot' window?

Tags: matplotlib

I found that matplotlib's `NavigationToolbar2Tk` 'configure plot' window is being pulled from `widgets.py`

for ref: https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/subplot_toolbar_01.pdf

The title for this window is **Click on slider to adjust subplot param**

Please advice me how to change its icon from default `tkinter` icon.

```
    self.axleft = toolfig.add_subplot(711)
    self.axleft.set_title('Click on slider to adjust subplot param')
    self.icon = self.resource_path('icon.ico')
    self.axleft.icon_bitmap = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.icon))
    self.axleft.wm_iconbitmap(self.icon)
    self.axleft.set_navigate(False)
```

I changed the above code starting in line 1115 in `widgets.py`. Here `self.resource_path` is a method I created to find the icon's path.

But getting error as subplots don't have the method `wm_icon_bitmap`

Comment: The icon is part of the GUI window. You cannot change it from within widgets.py (which is backend independent). Also in general you shouldn't change the source itself, unless its necessary to get rid of bugs. But if you need to, [this is the line](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/d888c07412c141b05e58212b74fba4c4b1847497/lib/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py#L592) to do it.

Comment: You nailed it! @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 
I will post the same as answer for future ref

Answer (score 1):

As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest pointed out.. I had to modify the `configure_subplots` method in **_backend_tk.py**. Used the `wm_icon_bitmap method` for the **Toplevel** widget.

```
def configure_subplots(self):
    toolfig = Figure(figsize=(6,3))
    window = Tk.Toplevel()
    icon = self.resource_path('icon.ico')
    window.icon_bitmap = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(icon))
    window.wm_iconbitmap(icon)
    canvas = type(self.canvas)(toolfig, master=window)
    toolfig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
    canvas.tool = SubplotTool(self.canvas.figure, toolfig)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
    window.grab_set()
```